# Swift Combine MergeMany Publishers

Tags: swift, networking, combine

I have a function that that builds several Publishers and returns them all in a single Publisher with MergeMany. The problem is that some users might have a LOT of endpoints in this publisher, and hitting all these endpoints at once frequently results in server timeouts. Is there a way to limit the concurrent network requests (like DispatchSemaphore) in Combine?

```
let mergedPubs = Publishers.MergeMany(urlRequests.map { dataTaskPublisher(for: $0)
            .decode(type: RawJSON.self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
            .mapError { _ in
                return URLError(URLError.Code.badServerResponse)
            }
    })
        .collect()
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no out of the box solution offered by Combine for this but we can build it on top of existing `Publishers.MergeMany` and `Publishers.Concatenate`.

The idea is:

- Divide the input array in chunks of max concurrent requests. Eg. using simple `Int` array `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]` and `maxConcurrent = 3` we will have `[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]` so requests 1, 2, 3 will be performed in parallel but 4, 5, 6 will only start when the previous chunk completes.
- Use `Publishers.MergeMany` on these subarrays. So we will get `[Publisher([1, 2, 3]), Publisher([4, 5, 6])]`
- Concatenate each new publisher coming out from the previous step.

To achieve this we need to essentially implement `Publishers.ConcatenateMany` leveraging `Publishers.Concatenate` that takes only 2 input streams. If you want to follow Combine style this should be implemented in a brand new struct but I implemented this in a static func for now.

```swift
extension Publishers {
  static func concatenateMany<Output, Failure>(_ publishers: [AnyPublisher<Output, Failure>]) -> AnyPublisher<Output, Failure> {
    return publishers.reduce(Empty().eraseToAnyPublisher()) { acc, elem in
      Publishers.Concatenate(prefix: acc, suffix: elem).eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
  }
```

Utility to chunk an Array:

```
extension Array {
  func chunked(into size: Int) -> [[Element]] {
    return stride(from: 0, to: count, by: size).map {
      Array(self[$0 ..< Swift.min($0 + size, count)])
    }
  }
}
```

And we can now implement a new version of `MergeMany` that takes also a `maxConcurrent` parameter.

```
extension Publishers {
  static func mergeMany<Output, Failure>(maxConcurrent: Int, _ publishers: [AnyPublisher<Output, Failure>]) -> AnyPublisher<Output, Failure> {
    return Publishers.concatenateMany(
      publishers.chunked(into: maxConcurrent)
        .map {
          Publishers.MergeMany($0)
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
        }
    )
  }
}
```

And finally your code would look like this:

```
let mergedPubs = Publishers.mergeMany(maxConcurrent: 3, requests)
  .collect()
  .eraseToAnyPublisher()
```

This is just one idea and there might be other ways to achieve the same result!

Comment: Thanks Fabio! I accepted your answer as I like the approach. In my specific case I ended up working it out with the backend engineer to reduce the number of calls I need to make. Previously I was requesting only a week of data at a time to reduce the response size, but the better solution was to request the entire time range and increase the response size limit.

Comment: Thank you very much! I was looking for a way to merge an array of publishers but merging the results respecting the order of the array and it seems that `concatenateMany` will do it.
One question though, how can you implement this in a Combine style, with the struct?

Answer (score 0):

Although @Fabio Felici has a cool solution to parallelizing work, in this particular case it seems like you have an error not show here solved by a solution not in this section of your code.

So in this case, it looks like you're creating a new session every time you call the method `dataTaskPublisher(for: $0)`. This makes it so that you're only limited by system resources on how many requests you'll make. The solution here is to keep one reference to 'URLSession' and create your data task publishers from that single instance. When creating the session, you should pass a configuration into the session's initializer and in that configuration, set `httpMaximumConnectionsPerHost` to the maximum concurrent connections you want to be making. You might do something like this:

```
struct RawJSON: Decodable {
    /// properties
}

class YourClass {
    
    let session = {
        /// Create a `URLSessionConfiguration`
        let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration()
        /// Set the maximum concurrent connections you want
        configuration.httpMaximumConnectionsPerHost = 10
        return URLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: nil, delegateQueue: nil)
    }()

    /// I am assuming this is what your `dataTaskPublisher` method looks like
    func dataTaskPublisher(for url: URL) -> URLSession.DataTaskPublisher {
        return session.dataTaskPublisher(for: url)
    }

    /// This is your method that you posted here
    func yourMethod(urlRequests: [URL]) {
        let mergedPubs = Publishers.MergeMany(urlRequests.map { dataTaskPublisher(for: $0)
                    .decode(type: RawJSON.self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
                    .mapError { _ in
                        return URLError(URLError.Code.badServerResponse)
                    }
            })
                .collect()
                .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}
```

If you wanted to get smart about it, you could dynamically change the number of concurrent operations based on whatever algorithm you choose. You might do something like this.

```
struct RawJSON: Decodable {
    /// properties
}

class YourClass {
    
    let operationQueue: OperationQueue
    let session: URLSession
    init() {
        /// Create a `URLSessionConfiguration`
        let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration()
        /// Create `OperationQueue`
        operationQueue = OperationQueue()
        /// Set the maximum concurrent connections you want
        configuration.httpMaximumConnectionsPerHost = 10
        session = URLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: nil, delegateQueue: nil)
    }

    /// I am assuming this is what your `dataTaskPublisher` method looks like
    func dataTaskPublisher(for url: URL) -> URLSession.DataTaskPublisher {
        return session.dataTaskPublisher(for: url)
    }

    /// This is your method that you posted here.
    func yourMethod(urlRequests: [URL]) {
        let mergedPubs = Publishers.MergeMany(urlRequests.map { dataTaskPublisher(for: $0)
                    .decode(type: RawJSON.self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
                    .mapError { _ in
                        return URLError(URLError.Code.badServerResponse)
                    }
            })
                .collect()
                .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
    
    /// Call this to change the number of concurrent operations in the queue
    func changeCuncurrentOperationCount(maxOperations: Int) {
        operationQueue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = maxOperations
    }
}
```